# C: writing content of array to txt file

Tags: c, stream, output

im trying to implement the number guessing game. The game itself works fine. But now I want to add a function which safes the score of the last game (Number of trys and guessed number) in the leaderboard.txt file.
I haven't finished the saveScore method yet, I don't need help with implementing the rest. I wan't to read the data from the file, add the new line and sort it from least to most trys. But I only wan't to save the top 10 of all time.
I need some help to get the following code running. One problem is the code doesn´t even terminate.

---

I think all the problems are within the saveScore method. (line 18 -25)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define max_length 300


void saveScore(int guess, int randNumber) {

    FILE *datei;
    datei = fopen("leaderboard.txt", "wb");

    
    char lines[max_length];
    char leaderboard[10][max_length];
    int line = 0;

    while (fgets(leaderboard[line], sizeof(lines), datei) != NULL){
            line++;  
    }

    leaderboard[line][max_length] = ("%d, %d", guess, randNumber);

    fwrite(leaderboard, sizeof(char), sizeof(leaderboard), datei);
    fclose(datei);
}

void startGame(){

    int guess = 1;
    int randNumber;
    int uInput;

    randNumber = (rand()%100)+1;
    printf("%d", randNumber);

        do {
        
        printf("Guess the number between 1-100: \n");
        scanf("%d", &uInput);

        if (uInput < randNumber){
            printf("the number you are looking for is higher.\n");
        }
        else if (uInput > randNumber){
            printf("the number you are looking for is lower.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Jackpot it was your %d. try.", guess);
        }
        guess++;
    } while (randNumber != uInput);

    saveScore(guess, randNumber);

    char playAgain = 'j';
    printf("Try Again (j/n): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &playAgain);
    
    if (playAgain == 'j') {
        startGame();
    }
    printf("Thank you for playing.");

}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
      
    startGame();

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help.
Best Enno

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You need to describe a specific problem and ask a more specific question than "need help". Is there a specific error or incorrect behaviour you are encountering?

Comment: You have an interesting mix of text input and binary output going on. If you're going to read line by line with `fgets` you'll want to write line by line with `fprintf`. In the end it won't matter because opening the file with `"wb"` as the mode destroys any existing contents. `"r+"` is probably the mode you want assuming you stick with a text file. You could use `"a"` to just write new data to the end of the file. `sprintf(leaderboard[line], "%d, %d", guess, randNumber);` would work to fill in the new value, as long as `line` never goes past 9.

Comment: @kaylum Okay, i will do in future questions. In this case the program doesn't terminate and therefore there is no error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks! Actually i wan't to read the data from the file, add the new line and sort it from least to most trys. But I only wan't to save the top 10 of all time. So I don't want to append data in a new line. I will add this information ,sorry.

Comment: What you probably want to do to keep your question focused is to concentrate on one thing at a time. You can always ask another question for the next thing if you need to. I would recommend writing a new program with some hardcoded score entries in it and focus on being able to write that data to a file, read it back, then write it to a new file. You've succeeded when both files are identical. Then you can move on to sorting the data and writing it. If the data is sorted you can check if a new entry is better than the last, replace it, then sort again to get it in the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop has the problem of being able to overflow `leaderboard` if `line` ever reaches `10`.

```
while (fgets(leaderboard[line], sizeof(lines), datei) != NULL){
    line++;  
}
```

This line

```
leaderboard[line][max_length] = ("%d, %d", guess, randNumber);
```

has a few problems. `[max_length]` would be one past the end of the buffer, but with that said, it is not needed and the assignment as a whole is incorrect. To perform string interpolation, use a function such as [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Aside from the fact that you only open the file for writing, the primary problem is that

```
fwrite(leaderboard, sizeof(char), sizeof(leaderboard), datei);
```

will write the *entire contents* of `leaderboard` to the file. This includes the garbage values that exist towards the end of each array, after each string. `fgets` will then read those garbage values later.

You should stick to reading and writing binary **or** text, but do not mix them. If you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), use [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) (or [similar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)) to write the text. Conversely, if you use [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), use [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) to read the binary data.

---

Here is a basic, cursory snippet using text functions, where we:

- open the file for *reading*
- read our lines into the array
- close the file
- add our new score to the array
- sort our array using [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)
- open the file for *writing*
- write our lines
- close the file

The trick here is `leaderboard` has an additional slot, so that there is always room for our newest score. After sorting, we only write at most `MAX_ENTRIES` entries to the file, meaning if the array is full we ignore the worst score.

```
#define MAX_ENTRIES 10
#define MAX_LENGTH 300
#define SAVE_FILE "leaderboard.txt"

int compare(const void *ap, const void *bp) {
    const char (*a)[MAX_LENGTH] = ap;
    const char (*b)[MAX_LENGTH] = bp;

    int av, bv;
    sscanf(*a, "%d", &av);
    sscanf(*b, "%d", &bv);

    return (av > bv) - (av < bv);
}

void saveScore(int guess, int randNumber) {
    char leaderboard[MAX_ENTRIES + 1][MAX_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    size_t entries = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(SAVE_FILE, "r");

    if (file) {
        while (entries < MAX_ENTRIES &&
                fgets(leaderboard[entries], sizeof *leaderboard, file))
            entries++;

        fclose(file);
    }

    sprintf(leaderboard[entries], "%d %d\n", guess, randNumber);
    entries++;
    qsort(leaderboard, entries, sizeof *leaderboard, compare);

    file = fopen(SAVE_FILE, "w");

    if (file) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < entries && i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++)
            fputs(leaderboard[i], file);

        fclose(file);
    }
}
```